# The intellij idea display mathematical method as symbols, how to disable this feature

Tags: intellij-idea

it display code like this:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hI4El.png)

but the actually code is:[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F53Eo.png)

so how to disable this feature, i have to move the mouse there to see what the code is.

Comment: Not sure if the duplicate link would completely solve your issue, but it seems like a good place to start reading.

Comment: thanks to @TimBiegeleisen, that's what I'm looking for;)